# How to create a secondary search for elements once index is exceeded

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```py
def feed_auto_like(x):
    likes = 0
    like_buttons = list(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='like']"))
    while likes < x:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", like_buttons[likes])
        likes += 1
        print(likes, 'Sucessful Likes')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", like_buttons[likes])
        time.sleep(5)
```

In this code, I search for elements once. However, I was wondering if I could somehow tell the function to search again and append it to the current list ONLY when it gets to the end of the current list. I want to prevent clicking on the same button twice, that's why.

I was considering adding this:

```py
like_buttons.append(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='like']"))
```

but if I put it inside the while loop, it'll add repetitions into the list. The search returns all the same like button with the same `id`. However, the position is of importance because I don't want to click it more than once.

I tried using a try-except block type; however, that was unsuccessful.